# How do I delete a re-writable CD-RW in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, compact-disc, cd-rw

I want to format my CD-RW to clear the data on it on Ubuntu 16.04. I have the dialog below to select options:

[image: format dialog]

But when I go to format it, it gives this error dialog:

> Error wiping device: Command-line `wipefs -a "/dev/sr0"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: wipefs: error: /dev/sr0: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
>    (udisks-error-quark, 0)

The drive is a DVD-R/RW drive and I can read the CD fine.

Comment: Do you want to wipe it completely (remove any existing partitions) or just wipe a filesystem that is already partitioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe wipefs failed because the disc is mounted? Run

```
lsblk
```

to check whether the optical drive is mounted, and do this to unmount it if needed:

```
sudo umount /dev/sr0
```

Then try running

```
wipefs -af /dev/sr0
```

where sr0 is whatever your optical drive actually is - double check to make sure!

Alternatively, try

```
cdrecord -v dev=/dev/sr0 blank=fast
```

Comment: If the OP wants to wipe the entire device than (albeit slow and ineffiecent) `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sr bs=512` may work too.

Comment: Yeah! The last line worked! But I had to install something called `wodim`. It wasn't mounted: `umount: /dev/sr0: not mounted`.

Comment: @Chloe Good to hear!